# How to add custom field at at a loop and show it in cart, order details, over view etc

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I'm using a WooCommerce plugin called WooCommerce Photography it shows helps to sell photographs, and we can make collection of photographs, this file is reasonable for showing product loops in the collection page

This is the template for displaying photography content within loops:
[content-photography.php](https://github.com/Irfan-Jamal/content-photography.php/blob/main/code)

I added the following to collect users note for photo editing in my file

```html
<div class="photoshop-note" style="display: block;">
    <label for="photoshop_note_text"><?php _e('Photoshop Note:', 'woocommerce'); ?></label>
    <textarea name="photoshop_note_text" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

Now I am stuck on How to handle the saving and displaying functionality.

I tried the following code:

```php
// Save Photoshop Note to Cart Item Data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_photoshop_note_to_cart', 10, 2);
function save_photoshop_note_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['_custom_photoshop_field']) && isset($_POST['photoshop_note_text'])) {
        $cart_item_data['photoshop_note'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['photoshop_note_text']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display Photoshop Note in Cart
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'display_photoshop_note_in_cart', 10, 3);
function display_photoshop_note_in_cart($product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    if (isset($cart_item['photoshop_note'])) {
        // Debugging: Output a message to check if the function is being triggered
        echo '<pre>Debug: Photoshop Note data - ' . print_r($cart_item['photoshop_note'], true) . '</pre>';

        $product_name .= '<div class="cart-photoshop-note">' . esc_html($cart_item['photoshop_note']) . '</div>';
    }
    return $product_name;
}


// Display Photoshop Note in Email
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'display_photoshop_note_in_email', 10, 3);
function display_photoshop_note_in_email($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text)
{
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $photoshop_note = $product->get_meta('photoshop_note');
        if ($photoshop_note) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('Photoshop Note:', 'your-theme-domain') . '</strong><br>' . esc_html($photoshop_note) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

// Display Photoshop Note in Order Details
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'display_photoshop_note_in_order_details', 10, 1);
function display_photoshop_note_in_order_details($order)
{
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $photoshop_note = $product->get_meta('photoshop_note');
        if ($photoshop_note) {
            echo '<p><strong>' . __('Photoshop Note:', 'your-theme-domain') . '</strong><br>' . esc_html($photoshop_note) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

But still no luck there is no photoshop note at cart that we written in note text area

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are those 2 fields displayed in single product pages?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec No, it's a collection page where many product loops are there.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec content-photography.php is reasonable for the content in each loop

Comment: what does mean "reasonable"?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it means anything we wanna show in the product loop we have to add in this file

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You can check live collection page here https://shop.foto-dino.de/collection/x-collection-for-x/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec When you check the photoshop checkbox you see it

Comment: So if it's in a loop, you need to add the loop number to the field name (attribute) like `<textarea name="photoshop_note_text-<?php echo $photography_loop['loop']; ?>" …` and same thing for the checkbox, because actually all fields in that loop have the same attribute name value and the same Ids…

Comment: On your link the page start displaying something then goes blank (a white page).

Comment: reload page, or try to go the homepage https://shop.foto-dino.de and then visit the link in my case it works

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Is this enough to change ids attributes, and name values? i